# Custom names to enumeration values

Tags: c#, enums, data-annotations

I have an enumeration of values that come through an API.

Those names are good but there is one I want to change with data annotations but how do you do that?

My enumeration looks like :

```
public enum TopicType
{
    All = 0,
    Message=1,
    CalendarEvent=2,
    Upload=4, 
    ToDo=8,
    ToDoList=16,
    Document=32
}
```

I want to change the "ToDo" to "ToDoItem" when I'm coding but I can't change the value in the enumeration due to serialization of my enum-object so I'll have to use data annotations, any suggestions?

Comment: Why you want to change  "ToDo" to "ToDoItem" when coding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think You can try over `[Display()]` Annotation.

I hope this what you are expecting..

Answer (score 7):

Regardless of why you want to change ToDo to ToDoItem (separate discussion), you can easily achieve it using the following approach:

```
public enum TopicType
{
  All = 0,
  Message=1,
  CalendarEvent=2,
  Upload=4, 
  [Display(Name = "ToDoItem")]
  ToDo=8,
  ToDoList=16,
  Document=32
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In which version was it added?

Comment: Version 3 (see the time-stamp) , but trust it will work with later versions as well

Comment: Odd, I'm not seeing it. I'm using 3.5 (With Unity 2017.3) - guessing it could be 3.6+.